# PHP and mpdf - Failed to load PDF in Chrome if charset_in='UTF-8'

Tags: php, google-chrome, utf-8, mpdf

I'm using mpdf to generate a pdf, and the way a did is something like this:

```
    header('Content-Type: application/pdf; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
    header('Accept-Ranges: bytes');
    define('MPDF_PATH', '../mpdf/');
    require(MPDF_PATH.'mpdf.php');
    require("../cnxdb.inc.php");
    error_reporting(E_ALL);
    ini_set('display_errors', 1);
    // some stuff to populate &html
    $html = is_utf8($html);
    $file_name = $title.'.pdf';
    ob_clean();
    $mpdf=new mPDF();
    $mpdf->SetTitle($title);
    $mpdf->setFooter($footer);
    $mpdf->allow_charset_conversion=true;
    $mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8'; 
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html);
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$file_name.'"');
    $mpdf->list_indent_first_level = 0;
    $mpdf->Output($file_name, 'I');
    $mpdf->debug = true;
```

But if I change the line $mpdf->charset_in='UTF-8' to $mpdf->charset_in='windows-1252' it prints the PDF, but some letters get scrambled, like ç, á, ó, ...
And this code works perfectly in Firefox, so it must be something to Chrome.
Does anyone know a solution to this? Or Chrome just don't go with PDFs with UTF-8?

Any extra info just ask me,
Thanks!

Comment: What if you ommit the in_charset and charset conversion completely? UTF-8 should be the default

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, it happens I am dumb and the charset has nothing to do to Chrome not loading.
The real problem was the  `$html`is line `$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);` had style in it, so Chrome gets crazy, but firefox was okay with it.
The solution is to separate style and html body:

```
$mpdf->WriteHTML($style, 1); // 1 is for stylesheet
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 2); // 2 is for html body
```

Good luck!